# In how many we can make a diode from BJT

Tags: diodes, bjt

I want to know about the different ways to connect a BJT as a diode. Could someone explain this?

Comment: I don't think you understand what a diode is and how it can applied to a BJT. Try searching on Google, "Diode model of a BJT".

Comment: Why would you want to use a BJT as a diode? What purpose does it serve instead of just buying a diode?

Comment: @winny Lol  are you after some editor badge to bring this question up after 4 years to correct its capitalization?

Comment: @tobalt Sorry, didn't realize how old it was. One link followed by another... No editor badges left for me.

Answer (score 2):

There's basically two ways, use the base and emitter or use the base and collector.

If you use the base and emitter it's a bit like a Zener diode (about 8 V typically).

If you use base and the collector it's more like an ordinary diode.

In both cases if you connect the unused terminal to the base it will amplify the conductivity of the diode.